# Ticket Price refund for missed connection

Tags: air-travel, airlines, refunds

I was on a return flight with Air China leaving Australia, stopping in China and finally arriving in London. I then had a flight booked for London to Turkey. Of course the Air China flight was delayed in Shanghai due to bad weather. As a result I missed the flight home to UK. Air China put me on a new flight a day later to London. 
However I missed the connecting flight with a different operator back to Turkey. As a result I had to buy a new ticket. This cost around 600 dollars. I enquired about some sort of refund. This is what they said:

> We regret to point out that the flight delay was caused by extraordinary circumstances which could not have been avoided even if all reasonable measures had been taken. We do strive to minimise disruption to our services, but delays/cancellation will from time to time inevitably occur. We are sure that you will appreciate that the safety of our passengers and crew is paramount, and that any adverse weather conditions must receive immediate attention in order to ensure complete peace of mind. We regret that whilst we appreciate your situation, your onward travel is beyond our area of responsibility, any other journeys or arrangements are the responsibility of individual passengers and we cannot reimburse such expense.

Do I have any rights as a customer?

Comment: Was this on two tickets or just one? And what did the people operating your flight to Turkey say when you spoke with them?

Answer (score 7):

If you are traveling on two separately bought tickets, it's your responsibility to leave enough time between them to catch the second flight even if the first one is late. If you have a good travel insurance, you might get a compensation. In any case try contacting the airlines, I heard that Korean Airlines gave a generous compensation in a similar situation, but I wouldn't keep my hopes high. Long story short; try your chance, but they don't owe you anything.

Comment: My experience agrees with this.  I learned the hard way, paying $2300 for the tuition.

Comment: This is true of all airports. I think it is a little foolish to book them separately as anything can happen.

Comment: It's not foolish if you're saving a huge amount of money by booking separate tickets.

Answer (score 1):

Check your travel insurance documents. Many policies will cover for this as long as you can prove you were delayed through circumstances beyond your control, even bad weather (barring war, civil unrest or terrorism). 600 dollars should be below the claim limit, and there's typically nil excess.